# How to download one file at time with wget bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, wget, download

So I have made this bash script to download multiple files from a website, I want to download these files in background hence "-b flag".

Script : list.sh

```
wget -b  -O filename.jpg  www.example.com/image1.jpg
wget -b  -O filename2.jpg  www.example.com/image2.jpg
wget -b  -O filename3.jpg  www.example.com/image4.jpg
```

How do I execute one command at a time ? I want to download one file at one time, then after 1st file is completed, I want to download second file etc.

When I am running `./list.sh`,
it starts to download all the files at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to run the **whole** script in background, so :

```
#!/bin/bash

wget -O filename.jpg   www.example.com/image1.jpg
wget -O filename2.jpg  www.example.com/image2.jpg
wget -O filename3.jpg  www.example.com/image4.jpg
```

Then:

```
$ screen
$ ./script
```

Now you can disconnect from Linux machine, then come back and retrieve the session:

```
$ screen -r
```

---

```
apt-cache show screen
[...]
Description-en: terminal multiplexer with VT100/ANSI terminal emulation
 GNU Screen is a terminal multiplexer that runs several separate "screens" on
 a single physical character-based terminal. Each virtual terminal emulates a
 DEC VT100 plus several ANSI X3.64 and ISO 2022 functions. Screen sessions
 can be detached and resumed later on a different terminal.
 .
 Screen also supports a whole slew of other features, including configurable
 input and output translation, serial port support, configurable logging,
 and multi-user support.
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, No I want to download "ONE FILE AT A TIME" with wget with help of the above bash script.
I have tried
wget -b  -O filename.jpg  www.example.com/image1.jpg &&
wget -b  -O filename2.jpg  www.example.com/image2.jpg && 
wget -b  -O filename3.jpg  www.example.com/image4.jpg
But It's not working.

Comment: Already understood. Telling to use background and running wget one by one is contradictory. Did you test my version ?

Comment: Yes, Tried your version & it's working great! <3 BUT, My main reason for trying to run it in Background [-b] is because I am using a VPS, & connecting and giving commands through PUTTY, therefore, If I disconnect putty, the whole process stops.. I would like to request you to please suggest a workaround that problem ?
I will try to run the script like "./list.sh &"

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the tremendous help, Gilles Sir. It worked exactly how you stated.  I am deeply grateful.